# commenting @extends('layouts.app') not working

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm starting a new project with laravel 5.8.

For this project we need a login page that displays only the login form (the default form provided by the auth scafold it's good enough).

Our difficulty comes when trying to remove the nav bar that comes in the login.blade.php.  Commenting out the @extends('layouts.app') doesn't remove it.

We tried to "go after" the issue throughout the routes, etc but with no luck too (we're all beginning our journey in the laravel world). This auth scaffold comes out of the basic example of simply returning a view on the routes...

my login.blade.php looks like this:

```html
<!-- @extends('layouts.app') -->

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf
                      <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                          <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                            <a href="{{ url('/login/redirect') }}" class="btn btn-danger ">
                              <span class="fa fa-google"></span> login with Google
                            </a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

even though the the first line is commented  the end result looks like this
[screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed0b8.png)

So I thought of asking is anyone knows how to properly remove the nav bar from the login page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you remove the `@extends('layouts.app')` you get nothing as output, you have to write your own layout. But if you really  want to disable it just write `<!-- @ extends('layouts.app') -->`

Comment: @dparoli `<!--` is what OP tried in their question. It won't work; see the excellent answer below.

Comment: @ceejayoz I add a space between `@` and `extends`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the HTML comment which will just comment out any markup that is outputted (and `@extends` doesn't output any HTML, it just registers the layout), but it doesn't tell blade to ignore it. Blade is parsed by PHP on the server, HTML is parsed by the browser on the client. You need to either remove the line or comment it out using [blade comments](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#comments)

```
{{-- @extends('layouts.app') --}}
```

Comment: it worked, but not as expected... If i remove that reference, it just return a blank page, so I have to do it another way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would expect that it would be because the layout is removed so all the styles included in the layout are also removed. To just remove the nav bar you would need to edit the `layouts/app.blade.php`  file

Comment: the night is your friend, and it reminded me I could simply use the --@auth and --@endauth tags on the blade. It solved the issue. Thanks again for the brainstorming